# Javascript - POST request from server/back-end doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, request

I am using an API for text-translatation ( you can find it here: [Yandex](https://translate.yandex.com/developers) ).

The following piece of code is in the front-end and works fine:

```
var url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate",
    keyAPI = "myKey/hidden";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    textAPI = "fa asta sa fie in engleza";
langAPI = "en";
data = "key="+keyAPI+"&text="+textAPI+"&lang="+langAPI;

xhr.open("POST",url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        var res = this.responseText;
        var json = JSON.parse(res);
        if (json.code === 200) {
            console.log( json.text[0]);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error Code: " + json.code);
        }
    }
};
```

The console in the browser outputs:

> do this to be in English

So it's fine.

However, I need to do this in the back-end. So, I know that *XMLHttpRequest* is built-in browser, but not in node, therefore I installed it using: npm install xmlhttprequest and I tried to use the same code as I used in the front-end, but I added a log on *xhr.onreadystatechange* to tell me the status:

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(this.status);
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
       var res = this.responseText;
       var json = JSON.parse(res);
       if (json.code === 200) {
             console.log( json.text[0]);
       }
       else {
             console.log("Error Code: " + json.code);
       }
    }
    };
```

And what I get is:

> 0

and

> 415

As the status.

So it didn't work. I decided to use request instead:

```
var url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate";
var keyAPI = "hidden;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var textAPI = "fa asta sa fie in engleza";
var langAPI = "en";

request.post({
       url: url,
       body: JSON.stringify({
          key : keyAPI,
          text: "tradu",
          lang : langAPI
       }),
       json: true
       }, function(err, response, body) {
               if(err) {
                   console.log(err);
                   return;
               }
               console.log(body);
       });
```

And the output I get is :

> { code: 415, message: 'Unsupported media type' }

So again, it doesn't work. I also tried adding headers in the post requests, like this:

```
headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

But it made no difference.

I did some digging and found out that status *415* means *Unsupported Media Type* and I also read some posts/fixes about this but none helped me.

Comment: never heard about this `xmlhttprequest` module, why use this when you have much simpler methods, like [the built-in "http"](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)?

Comment: I think you don't have to `JSON.stringify` in passing body in the request.

Comment: @vibhor1997a it has the same behavior regardless if I use it or not

Comment: @Kaddath because I didn't have to re-write any code.

Comment: In the working example, you're using Content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Did you try using the same with the node based libraries?

Comment: well, if i were you i'd rewrite this code anyway. No error handling, poor support for the `xhr` object which behaves differently on some browsers (when it exists and doesn't have a different name).. but you do as you like (saving these 5 min now will probably make you loose hours later imo)

Comment: @Kaddath why would I re-write it using HTTP when I already have a version of it in REQUEST? makes no sense

Comment: @LazyElephant as I said in the post, I copy-pasted that code to the back-end. Or do you mean to use the equivalent of that in node? If that's what you meant, I did not.

Comment: sorry but as you left `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` in that piece of code, i didn't go further reading it, you should remove it. We can't read all posts in very detailled way and sometimes stop on the first "error" we see

Comment: @Kaddath but it doesn't give an error, it works fine, I am doing something wrong, however.

Comment: " I am doing something wrong, however"....yeah Kaddath's point is that what you're doing wrong is expecting that code to work properly on the server-side

Comment: @ADyson Why? how do requests from the back-end differ from those from the front-end? what did I do wrong? what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Well I don't know, but you downloaded some random plugin so who knows whether it works properly. It has a list of known issues on the npm page. And as Kaddath said your implementation of an ajax request is poor anyway, so perhaps the plugin doesn't support the way you've done it. And there's no need to use ajax / XHR on the server, it's totally browser based concept. There exist proper libraries for making HTTP requests from the server-side, as already mentioned, which will be simpler to use.

Comment: It gives the same output with 'request', which is a "proper libraries for making HTTP requests from the server-side".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it to work, use the `form` key to send your data (using request)

```
var url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate";
var keyAPI = "hidden";
var textAPI = "fa asta sa fie in engleza";
var langAPI = "en";

request.post({
   url: url,
   form: {
     text: textAPI,
     key: keyAPI,
     lang: langAPI
   },
   }, function(err, response, body) {
           if(err) {
               console.log(err);
               return;
           }
           console.log(body);
   });
```